Debugging in VS code doesnot results any output Pyqt5 .ui file


import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
class MyForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        loadUi('dm.ui',self)
        self.pbClick.clicked.connect(self. display_message)
    def display_message(self):
        self.label_2.SetText("Hello "+self.leName.text())
    if __name__=="__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        ex = MyForm()
        ex.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())

i tried loading .ui file in python code and debugging , i see no results

Why do you expect that debugging in VS Code should create a .ui file?

Looks like you need a UI file, use Qt Designer to design one. Here's a dm.ui that appears to demonstrate your code functionality, try adding it to your code base: https://dpaste.org/UZyiE

The if __name__ has the wrong indentation level, and display_message will raise an exception because the function name is setText(), not SetText(). As said above, the fact that you're using debugging is irrelevant, and in any case uic functions do not create ui files to begin with.
